# Django DateTimeField to compare with datetime.now()

Tags: python, django

I have a `DateTimeField`:

```
class Assignment (models.Model):
   official_deadline = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I need to compare it to current date time, I have tried :

```
def official_deadline_past(self):
    if datetime.datetime.today() > self.official_deadline:
        return True
    return False
```

But it returns always `False` I have also tried:

```
def official_deadline_past(self):
    if datetime.datetime.now() > self.official_deadline:
        return True
    return False
```

But I have the same problem.

I have an information in the field: `2011-07-02 00:00:00` for example in the form generated by `ModelForm`

Comment: The code you've posted should work. Could you add a bit more detail. If you print/log the value of `self.official_deadline` in the method, what is the value?

Comment: I agree with Alasdair - you need to check the values that the comparison is returning.  This is when I love to use the django shell.

Comment: I have : `datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 2, 5, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)` when I ask a `assignment.official_deadline`. And `<bound method Assignment.official_deadline_past of <Assignment: nom>>` when I ask a `assignment.official_deadline_past`

Comment: @Nico401 did you find a solution for this problem? Facing the same where I try to filter objects for current date

Comment: Sorry it is long time ago, I don't remember what was the roots of this problem. I only have one removed answer I have posted : "It was a problem with UTC, I have deactivated it..".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue comparing DateTimeField with datetime under python 2.7.3 and django 1.3.1

I don't think DateTimeField had good timezone support then or I didnt have it configured properly.

Whenever I specified a timezone for datetime field all my comparisons of DateTimeField > datetime would fail.

datetime was using local central time while DateTimeField was entered as eastern.

I ended up just putting a stupid hack in to add a timedelta(hours=1) to the datetime central object to "convert" it to eastern.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue , django model Datetime Field like only contain date(without time)

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

q1=Q()
q1.children.append(Q(datetimefieldFrom__lte=now))
q1.children.append(Q(datetimefieldTo__gte=now))
```

ex.
now : "2020-12-11 17:17:58.000000"
datetimeFrom : "2020-12-11 16:17:58.000000"
datetimeFrom : "2020-12-11 18:17:58.000000"

it just pass "2020-12-11 00:00:00.000000" to compare

@johnjamesmiller, your timezone issue can be solve by modify the setting.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Hong_Kong'

USE_TZ = True
```